# How to know exact the line and description of error which is occurred when executing BeanShell program in jMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

```
Assertion error: true
Assertion failure: false
Assertion failure message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: source   Sourced file: ../../InputFiles/Scripts/minimal-json.bsh
```

This error is occurring when I am executing my BeanShell program.
I checked jmeter.log file and it is giving similar error.

```
2016/11/15 16:11:40 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: source Sourced file: ../../InputFiles/Scripts/minimal-json.bsh 
2016/11/15 16:11:40 WARN  - jmeter.assertions.BeanShellAssertion: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: source    Sourced file: ../../InputFiles/Scripts/minimal-json.bsh
```

By using *try* and *catch*, I got the exception and store it in `log.info(e)`. But it was also giving the same error.

How to get exact error line & description of the error(like variable is not defined or No such method,etc.,).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log.info(e)` contains the error itself as String is expected and you pass Exception there. I would suggest using another method, to wit: [Logger.error(String message, Throwable throwable)](http://excalibur.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/log/Logger.html#error(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable)) like:

```
try {
    int i = 1 / 0;
}
catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Error in Beanshell: ", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

It will work like:

[image: Beanshell try/catch]

Another troubleshooting techique is adding [debug()](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#debug) directive to the beginning of your Beanshell script - this way you will get exhaustive information on your script executin in [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29)

See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any way to get the line number also in Log Viewer.

Comment: For inlined scripts - no, for scripts originated from source files it should be automatically